# How To Execute EMF and GMF?

Tags: emf, eclipse-gmf

Hello Everyone I am new to work with EMF and GMF. Can any one help me **how to create EMF and GMF** project in Eclilpse. I mean to ask what are the **tools required** for this to execute.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is an own Eclipse Project for this. Best would be to Download the All-in-One Update Site from https://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/downloads/ and to read about EMF there.
You can also find the minimum requirements there. To Understand how you create an EMF project I would recommend to work through this http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/emf-tutorial/
Hope this helps. If not please try to be more specific about your question.